# How to Encrypt the data of djanog.ckeditor Richtextfield?

Tags: django, django-models, cryptography

***Hi There actually i am creating a notes taking app using django. For better ux i have used django ckeditor for providing a good editor to write beautiful and informative notes. I have  used django.ckeditor richtextfield for this purpose. Now i want to encrypt the data of this text field so it can be stored safefly. I have used djanog-cryptography package and used encrypt method.
Problem -: When i am retreiving the note_contents in my template its showing nothing.
I am attaching my views and models and settings.py***

---

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . models import UserCreatedNote
from . forms import AddNoteForm
# Create your views here.
@login_required
def notes(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AddNoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.user = request.user
            form_data.save()
            
        notes = UserCreatedNote.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        form = AddNoteForm()
        context = {'notes': notes,'add_note_form':form}
        return render(request,'usernotes.html',context)
    
    notes = UserCreatedNote.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    form = AddNoteForm()
    context = {'notes': notes,'add_note_form':form}
    return render(request,'usernotes.html',context)
@login_required
def edit(request,id):
    note = get_object_or_404(UserCreatedNote, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddNoteForm(request.POST, instance=note)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.user = request.user
            print(form_data.id)
            
            
            
            
            form_data.save()
      
        form = AddNoteForm(instance=note)
        context={'note':note,'u_form':form}
    
        return render(request,'edit_note.html',context)
    
    
   
    form = AddNoteForm(instance=note)
    context={'note':note,'u_form':form}
    
    return render(request,'edit_note.html',context)

@login_required
def delete(request,id):
    note = UserCreatedNote(id=id,user=request.user)
    note.delete()
    return redirect('/user/notes/')
```

---

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for keepsafe project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = config('DEBUG') 
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "useraccounts.keepsafeusermodel"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    
    'useraccounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend',
)
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'useraccounts.apps.UseraccountsConfig',
    'notes.apps.NotesConfig',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    'ckeditor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'keepsafe.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['notes/templates/notes','useraccounts/templates/useraccounts','keepsafe/templates/keepsafe'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'keepsafe.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER':'',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':''
        
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'user_profile'
LOGIN_URL = 'user_login'

if not DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = '587'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''






CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    # 'toolbar': None, You can change this based on your requirements.
    'width': 'auto',

          },
    }

# CRYPTOGRAPHY_BACKEND = 'cryptography.hazmat.backends.default_backend()'
# CRYPTOGRAPHY_DIGEST = 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA256'
# CRYPTOGRAPHY_KEY = None
# CRYPTOGRAPHY_SALT = 'django-cryptography'
# SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django_cryptography.core.signing.TimestampSigner'


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

https://django-cryptography.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

when i use this in my settings it throws an error that **'str has no object digest_size'** something.

---

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django_cryptography.fields import encrypt
# Create your models here.
class UserCreatedNote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note_title = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    note_tags = encrypt(models.CharField(default='',max_length=20,blank=True,null=True))
    note_contents = RichTextField(default='',max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        
        ordering = ['-creation_time',]
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class UserQueries(models.Model):
    email = models.TextField(default="",primary_key=True,max_length=80)
    name = models.CharField(default="",max_length=80)
    subject = models.CharField(default="",max_length=100)
    message= models.CharField(default="",max_length=5000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```